# Can I set up a hand written signature in iOS mail app?

Tags: ios, mail.app, signature

Or must I copy and paste each time?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to compose a multiline signature that'll apply to all your messages:

> Settings » Mail, Contacts, Calendars » Signature

Additionally, you can also use:

> Settings » General » Keyboard » Shortcuts

And compose multiple keyboard auto-expanding shortcuts. By using clever shortcut tags (e.g., l1, l2, etc.), you can quickly make multiple lines of text for a seemingly multiline signature.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for corporate use, there are tools that can manage this from the mail server (see for example [this one](http://www.exclaimer.com)).

If it's for your personal mail, there's [this App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-html-signature/id423591484?mt=8) for a dollar that will take your details straight from the iPhone's settings.